# Windows Media Player Play to - failed to retrieve media information from media server

Tags: video, windows-media-player, video-streaming, codec, xbox-video

So, I'm recently having issues playing any sort of mp4 file to my xbox one.
Everytime I try, I just get the message "Failed to retrieve media information from media server".

I've tried the common trick of restarting the WMP network service and UPNP device service several times, to no avail.. I ALWAYS get the same problem.

This is what I get every single time:
[image: Step1]
[image: Step2]

But this is where it gets a bit weird; some other, slightly older mp4 files I have that used to work fine, are STILL working fine:
[image: working example]

I've read that this may be down to the source file codec not being supported by the player, but when I compare the failing files codec info (obtained by mediainfo):

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\Users\sk93\Videos\B.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 1.55 GiB
Duration                                 : 2h 45mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 1 336 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 2h 45mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 1 204 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 40.0 Mbps
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 354 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.034
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.157
Stream size                              : 1.39 GiB (90%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2453 ea0ca51
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=4 / deblock=1:-1:-1 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=9 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.15 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=18 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=0 / chroma_qp_offset=-3 / threads=10 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / slices=4 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=1 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=29 / keyint_min=2 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=29 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=21.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=10 / qpmax=51 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=40000 / vbv_bufsize=30000 / crf_max=0.0 / nal_hrd=vbr / filler=0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 2h 45mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 151 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 152 MiB (10%)
Language                                 : English
```

With that of a working mp4 file:

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\Users\sk93\Videos\C.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 931 MiB
Duration                                 : 2h 15mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 958 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 2h 15mn
Bit rate                                 : 860 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 24.6 Mbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 536 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.40:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.052
Stream size                              : 836 MiB (90%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2409 d6b4e63
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=4 / deblock=1:-1:-1 / analyse=0x3:0x133 / me=umh / subme=9 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.15 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=24 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=0 / chroma_qp_offset=-3 / threads=60 / lookahead_threads=4 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=23 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=60 / rc=2pass / mbtree=1 / bitrate=860 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / vbv_maxrate=31250 / vbv_bufsize=31250 / nal_hrd=none / filler=0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 2h 15mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 93.8 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 106 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 91.2 MiB (10%)
Language                                 : English
```

I can't see any difference that would matter?

Totally stumped :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and as if by magic.. I stumble upon a "workaround" almost immediately after posting this!
Simply renaming the .mp4 files to .avi seems to "fix" the problem of not being able to play the files.
(no.. really!)

only downside is that seeking isn't supported, but I can live with that until a better answer can be found!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had the same problem when trying to play *some* .mp4 files stored on my Windows 7 PC to my LG Smart TV today.

I renamed them to .avi & they then played just fine.
I then renamed them back to .mp4 & they now also play just fine.